# how can i use caching using coreData?

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios4, uiimage

In my application, i m using images in table view. these images are getting downloaded everytime, when i scroll up and down. to make the downloaded images in the cell, caching must be used with coredata. Is there any link for it. LazyTableImages. which is tedious, anything simple to explain...

Comment: Need more detail. Are you storing the images as transformable attributes in a Core Data entity or are you downloading them from somewhere else?

Comment: I get images from XMLwebservices, and directly displaying it in a table cells.